Facebook Server Sent Event for Live Comments error with status code 404
I'm trying to get comments from Facebook live_videos with Facebook SSE.
Despite I can easily retrieve comments with the {live-video-id}/comments graph api using my test app's page access token, I can't make the SSE to work with the same access token.
Trying to connect with eventsource (code below)  keep giving { type: 'error', status: 404, message: 'Not Found' }
async execute() {
    this.es = new EventSource(
      `https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/${live_video_id}/live_comments?access_token=${page_access_token}`,
    );
    this.es.onopen = (ev) => {
      console.log('onopen', ev);
    };
    this.es.onmessage = (ev) => {
      console.log('onmessage', ev);
    };
    this.es.onerror = (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    };
  }

Is there anything else that I'm still missing to get the SSE to work?
